How to use different yarn versions in separate projects on the same system
I am working on two projects on my Mac OS, let's call them Project1 and Project2.
Project1 uses yarn version 3.1.1
Project2 uses yarn version 1.22.22.
This project has been around for several years, hence uses an older yarn version.
The projects are too big to perform a full version upgrade at once. My work involves switching between the projects frequently. So, I have to switch yarn versions every time.
Is there a way to have two different yarn versions in the two projects?
I have tried to uninstall yarn globally and install different versions in the two projects. But it hasn't worked.

Include "packageManager": "yarn@3.1.1" & "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.22" in the respective projects' package.json
And as the yarn docs suggest use corepack enable. Make sure you remove the existing yarn global installation
Now just do yarn -v to check the versioning & then yarn install
Note: If you don't want to use pnp packages, create a .yarnrc.yml file in the root of the project & add  nodeLinker: node-modules
